# Why does the following JavaScript function not print anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have taken the following example from "Hands-on Node".  It uses some reasonably advanced techniques.  I have copied the code verbatim and have tried to debug a few times but cannot figure out why nothing gets printed to my console.

```
var schedule = function(timeout, callbackfunction) {
    return {
        start: function() {
            setTimeout(callbackfunction, setTimeout)
        }
    }
};

(function() {
    var timeout = 1000;
    var count = 0;
    schedule(timeout, function doStuff() {
        console.log(++ count);
        schedule(timeout, doStuff);
    }).start(timeout);
})();
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your code, in: setTimeout(callbackfunction, setTimeout), the second parameter should be "timeout"

Comment: Hmm, I recommend using other learning resources than this book...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from passing `setTimeout` instead of `timeout` *(which will still allow it to run once)*, if this is meant to loop the timer, then there's a flaw.

The code never calls `.start()` again after the first time. You'd need to do this...

```
(function() {
    var timeout = 1000;
    var count = 0;
    schedule(timeout, function doStuff() {
        console.log(++ count);
        schedule(timeout, doStuff).start(); // Invoke .start() each time
    }).start(); // Removed useless "timeout" argument
})();
```

I don't know why someone would take this approach, as it seems overly complex.

---

I'm not even sure why they were passing `timeout` to the inital `.start()`. That function doesn't use any argument passed. I updated to remove it.

---

If this was meant to teach about the benefit of closures, then this example really does little to do that.

Yes, the `.start()` function does reference the `timeout` and `callbackfunction` parameters, but the object returned is used once and discarded, at which point we call `schedule` again, and pass it the same args.

It would seem more useful as a demonstration if `schedule` just returned a function, and you retained a reference to that function. It would then only require the one call to `schedule` to hold the values.

```
var schedule = function(timeout, callbackfunction) {
    return function() {
        setTimeout(callbackfunction, timeout)
    }
};

(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var fn;
    (fn = schedule(1000, function doStuff() { // 1. assign the function returned
        console.log(++ count);
        fn();  // 3. invoke the same function again
    }))();  // 2. invoke the returned function immediately
})();
```

Comment: Right.  `setInterval` anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The 'start' function in the anonymous returned by the 'schedule' function has a typo - it should call "setTimeout" with the argument "timeout", not "setTimeout":

```
var schedule = function(timeout, callbackfunction) {
  return {
    start: function() {
      setTimeout(callbackfunction, timeout); // Fix the second arg.
    }
  }
};
```

Also, the "doStart()" function call never calls the anonymous "start()" function again, so the log statement would only execute once.